# What formatting is allowed for systemd option lines in general?

Tags: systemd, init

Im writing some systemd service files currently and wonder about what is allowed to properly format their content so I can improve readability and such for me. It's pretty much a question about if I'm able to implement some code style at all.

What I've [read so far](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/systemd.unit.5.html) is about support for comments, that some options support spaces for e.g. a list of values and that `\` can be used to concatenate multiple lines. That's pretty much it as general advices. What I didn't read is thorough documentation about the key-value-pairs itself, e.g. if one is allowed to put spaces or tabs before/after a key name and before a value to indent lines and all that stuff.

The following is one example of what I'm asking myself:

```
[Unit]
Description=some pretty long description \
            spanning multiple lines
RequiresMountsFor=/tmp
```

vs.

```
[Unit]
Description       = some pretty long description \
                    spanning multiple lines
RequiresMountsFor = /tmp
```

vs.

```
[Unit]
    Description       = some pretty long description \
                        spanning multiple lines
    RequiresMountsFor = /tmp
```

Is there any docs available describing what is possible regarding formatting of options? Or is the lack of such already the sign that what I would like to have is not possible at all? Else would be [documented in the man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/systemd.unit.5.html)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of [April 2016](https://lists.freedesktop.org/archives/systemd-devel/2016-April/036100.html), there is no formal definition of the syntax.

---

I think the closest you'll fine in the [documentation](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html) is this line:

> The syntax is inspired by [XDG Desktop Entry Specification](http://standards.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/latest/) `.desktop` files, which are in turn inspired by Microsoft Windows `.ini` files.
>
> ...
>
> Note that using multiple assignments to the same value makes the unit file incompatible with parsers for the XDG `.desktop` file format.

From there, we can go to the [section describing the "basic format of the file"](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/latest/ar01s03.html), which claims:

> #### Entries
>
> Entries in the file are `{key,value}` pairs in the format:
>
> `Key=Value`
>
> Space before and after the equals sign should be ignored; the `=` sign is the actual delimiter.
>
> Only the characters `A-Za-z0-9-` may be used in key names.
>
> As the case is significant, the keys `Name` and `NAME` are not equivalent.
>
> Multiple keys in the same group may not have the same name. Keys in different groups may have the same name.

Unfortunately, [according to some messages to the mailing list](https://lists.freedesktop.org/archives/systemd-devel/2010-July/000098.html), it does deviate in a few places... and short of looking at the source code of the parser there does not appear to be any explicit documentation.

---

You can use `systemd-analyze verify <file>` to validate your unit files. https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/3677

Answer (score 0):

I would visit the `systemd` man page on your system.
The format seems to be specified in section 5, e.g. [see here](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/systemd.unit.5.html).
You can invoke this e.g. by `man 5 systemd`.

Comment: That's what I was reading and referring to. So you are saying nothing beyond what is mentioned there is possible? I hoped it would only be a lack of documentation.

Comment: OK, you did not mention this in your original question. No, I did not make any claim about the availibility of other sources. If in doubt do some experiments. You might dig through [the source](https://github.com/systemd/systemd) for the parser and its grammar. And the [project page](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/)  might give you pointers to additional resources.

Comment: @mvw This is not an answer. It should be deleted.

Comment: @jpaugh No need to delete, mvw was right, my question didn't mention I already read that man page and was unclear. While not strictly what I'm looking for, links to those man pages often help.